# ¿Cómo seria la función para obtener el numero máximo,mínimo y posición de una matriz?

Tags: c, funciones

En si, el programa pide valores desde teclado y crea una matriz de 5 por 5,suma las filas y las columnas pero ahora me pide una función para obtener el valor mínimo, máximo y la posición de estos mediante una función.

```
valmax(int matriz[5][5])
{
    int d, t, aux;
    aux = matriz[0][0];
    for (d = 0; d < 5; d++) {
        for (t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
            if (matriz[d][t] > matriz[d + 1][t + 1]) {
                aux = matriz[d][t];
            }
        }
    }
    return aux;
}

int main()
{
    aux = valmax(matriz);
    for (d = 0; d < 5; d++) {
        for (t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
            if (matriz[d][t] == aux)
                break;
        }
    }
    fprintf(recibo, "posicion[%d][%d] y valor maximo es: %d", d, t, aux);
    return 0;
}
```

Ésto es solo para el valor maximo,me falta el valor minimo,espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto que has escrito no puede funcionar para calcular el máximo. Piensa que en la función estás comparando cada elemento `matriz[d][t]`, no con el siguiente, sino con `matriz[d + 1][t + 1]`, osea, una columna más y una fila debajo. Lo cual no tiene ningún sentido si lo que quieres es recorrer toda la matriz.

Se me ocurre algo más sencillo: Guarda el primer elemento como el mayor y luego vete comparando ese valor con cada uno de la matriz, uno a uno con todos. Si el de la matriz es mayor que el que te has guardado, te guardas el de la matriz y continuas. Al final del recorrido tendrás guardado el mayor. Si ya de paso te guardas la posición x e y del elemento que ha sido mayor, al terminar tendrás también la posición, con un solo recorrido. Tu función quedaría algo así:

```
int valmax(int matriz[5][5], int * x, int * y)
{
    int d, t, aux;
    aux = matriz[0][0];
    for (d = 0; d < 5; d++) {
        for (t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
            if (matriz[d][t] > aux) {
                aux = matriz[d][t];
                *x = d;
                *y = t;
            }
        }
    }

    return aux;
}
```

Fíjate que la función retorna el valor máximo y posiciona en `x` y en `y` la posición del elemento. Al salir de la función, tendrás en el retorno el máximo, y en `x` e `y` su posición.

La llamada a la función sería algo así:

```
int main()
{
    int matriz[ 5][ 5];
    int d = 0;
    int t = 0;

    //Relleno la matriz con valores para el ejemplo
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for( int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            matriz[ i][ j] = i + j;
        }
    }
    //Pongo un valor conocido, más grande que los demás, para probar que
    //este va a ser el mayor y que va a estar en la posición [2][3]
    matriz[2][3] = 115;

    int posx, posy;
    int aux = valmax(matriz, &posx, &posy);

    printf("posicion[%d][%d] y valor maximo es: %d", posx, posy, aux);
    return 0;
}
```

Para calcular el menor sería exactamente igual pero cambiando el sentido de la comparación en la función:

```
if (matriz[d][t] < aux) {
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, me ayudaste bastante.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo seria la función para obtener el numero máximo,mínimo y posición de una matriz?

En C no existen las funciones que devuelvan más de un valor, salvo que sea un valor compuesto, por ejemplo:

```
typedef struct elemento
{
    int x, y, valor;
} elemento;

elemento maximo(int matriz[5][5]);
elemento minimo(int matriz[5][5]);
```

Sabiendo esto, puedes recorrer los elementos de la matriz recordando el mayor o menor valor recorrido:

```
elemento maximo(int matriz[5][5])
{
    elemento resultado;
    resultado.x = -1;
    resultado.y = -1;
    resultado.valor = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; ++y)
        {
            if (matriz[x][y] > resultado.valor)
            {
                resultado.x = x;
                resultado.y = y;
                resultado.valor = matriz[x][y];
            }
        }
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Valora que esta solución no tiene en cuenta números negativos.